# sum all of previous value with one row formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to sum-up all of previous value.
for example like image.

If current cell is C2, then show A2.

If current cell is C3, then show SUM(A2:A3).

If current cell is C4, then show SUM(A2:A4)

[image]

Comment: You've virtually answered it yourself !! :) I think your just missing the $ anchor to make it pull downable.

Comment: I want to use arrayFormula, if I use SUM formula, I need to copy formula by each row

Comment: I'm not that much of an expert to know why you would want an array for this as opposed to simple sum, but sure the same logic will apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably more alternatives, but try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),(SUMIF(ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A),A2:A)),))
```

Answer (score 2):

So in cell C2 , your start cell, put:

=Sum(A$2:A2)

Now copy paste it to all the cells in the column you want - C,  or simply Drag Down the formula.

Answer (score 0):

try in C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="";;MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(A2:A500)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A500)))*A1:A500); SIGN(A2:A500))))
```